# Creating a ternary plot

Tags: r

I don't know how to do this because I'm new to R and the codes seem confusing. I saw the following codes on a web site and was trying to apply them to my own work.

```
#Load the data
df <- read.table(file = "~/Desktop/PPS-data.txt", header = T)

#Create the plot and store
plot <- ggtern(data = df, aes(x = Xyp, y = XO, z = XY)) +
           geom_point(aes(fill = Root),
                          size = 4,
                          shape = 21,
                          color = "black") +
           ggtitle("PPS 3-State Model") +
           labs(fill = "Root States") +
           theme_tern_rgbw() +
           theme(legend.position      = c(0,1),
                 legend.justification = c(0, 1))
```

The data file they used was not available, so I couldn't look at it to see how it was arranged.

Here is my data:

```
GRAVEL  SAND    MUD
0.95    93.55   5.49
8.06    44.38   47.55
1.76    79.35   18.89
10.11   87.37   2.53
1.35    90.03   8.62
6.07    75.00   18.93
4.07    95.93   0.00
5.12    94.83   0.05
4.31    75.01   20.68
1.97    71.94   26.10
4.47    77.36   18.17
1.64    78.70   19.66
2.01    70.74   27.25
7.64    82.50   9.86
12.35   82.86   4.79
4.38    79.94   15.68
11.48   84.61   3.91
0.82    91.65   7.53
36.79   63.21   0.00
6.01    41.29   52.70
17.26   23.22   59.52
8.41    41.29   50.30
5.45    39.20   55.34
2.22    19.71   78.07
0.73    14.79   84.48
7.43    51.54   41.03
4.78    48.75   46.47
6.73    48.52   44.75
10.89   45.73   43.38
1.62    22.22   76.16
1.90    19.73   78.37
3.00    25.31   71.69
1.75    17.00   81.25
1.81    21.60   76.59
2.61    30.07   67.32
2.27    31.28   66.44
1.09    26.82   72.08
1.04    17.31   81.65
0.99    12.39   86.62
0.96    17.23   81.81
```

Comment: Well, for starters, in the example you took from the website, `df` must have columns named `Xyp`, `XO`, `XY`, and `Root`. In your dataset, you have columns names `GRAVEL`, `SAND`, and `MUD'.

Comment: I named my columns with their header, i got error !

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? OP provided code and sample data.

Comment: Can you clarify please...

Comment: I'm not sure why you posted the same question again, maybe by accident?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started with

```
library(ggtern)
ggtern(df,aes(GRAVEL,SAND,MUD))+geom_point()
```

[image]

Adding `fill=Root` within the `aes()` function and `shape=21` outside would colour in the points according to the value of some other variable, but it only makes most sense to colour the points if you have a separate variable in your data set which could determine the colour -- your example above only provides three variables (you could colour them randomly, but that seems a bit silly).

Comment: Can you explain how you did that please ?

Comment: ...I'm interested in having colourful plots like the examples on this webpage, can you teach me how ? http://www.ggtern.com/2013/12/16/pps-3-state-model/

Comment: OK. Now I'm feeling the downvote. Replace `aes(x = Xyp, y = XO, z = XY)` in your code with `aes(x = GRAVEL, y = SAND, z = MUD)`. Remove `aes(fill=Root)`. Everything else is the same.

Comment: (1) it makes most sense to colour the points if you have a separate variable in your data set which will determine the colour -- you've only given use three variables (you could colour them randomly, but that seems a bit silly). (2) If your data set is called `df` then the two lines of code I gave should work (you'll need to have installed the `ggtern` package first). (3) A good way to learn for yourself is to go back and forth between the simple working example I gave above and the full example from the web page -- experiment with adding different components and see what they do.

Comment: @Ben Bolker...'Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class function'

Comment: What is your data frame called?  My code will only work if your data frame is called `df`.  Otherwise you'll get this error. (`df` is also the name of a built-in R function: if I had more sensibly used a name like `my_data`, you would have gotten `"object 'my_data' not found"`)

Comment: I know that experts can overlook difficulties sometimes, but I can't see how I could have presented this any more simply!

Comment: IMO [this](http://www.statmethods.net/index.html) is an excellent place to start learning R. [This site](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) provides an excellent introduction to `ggplot`, with many, many examples. Finally, there is a [whole site](http://www.ggtern.com) dedicated to the `ggtern` package, with many tutorials, [starting here](http://www.ggtern.com/usage-basic/). SO is really not the place for tutorials.